# Clients not updating with approved updates from WSUS

Tags: active-directory, windows-xp, windows-update, wsus

I've been a bit behind in my windows XP updates recently, and I have about 18 or so I need to roll out to all our users, according to WSUS. I'm trying it on a couple of test PCs, and so far i've had no luck. On each one, one update would install (and need a reboot), and nothing else since. When I run wuauclt.exe /detectnow, I get this in the windowsupdate.log:

```
2009-10-29  17:27:10:624    1128    93c AU  Triggering AU detection through DetectNow API
2009-10-29  17:27:10:624    1128    93c AU  Triggering Online detection (non-interactive)
2009-10-29  17:27:10:624    1128    504 AU  #############
2009-10-29  17:27:10:624    1128    504 AU  ## START ##  AU: Search for updates
2009-10-29  17:27:10:624    1128    504 AU  #########
2009-10-29  17:27:10:624    1128    504 AU  <<## SUBMITTED ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {59353978-CBA7-4B0B-AFD3-515577D3C16B}]
2009-10-29  17:27:10:624    1128    a14 Agent   *************
2009-10-29  17:27:10:624    1128    a14 Agent   ** START **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
2009-10-29  17:27:10:624    1128    a14 Agent   *********
2009-10-29  17:27:10:624    1128    a14 Agent     * Online = Yes; Ignore download priority = No
2009-10-29  17:27:10:624    1128    a14 Agent     * Criteria = "IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Installation' and IsAssigned=1 or IsHidden=0 and IsPresent=1 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' and IsAssigned=1 or IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=1 and DeploymentAction='Installation' and IsAssigned=1 and RebootRequired=1 or IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' and IsAssigned=1 and RebootRequired=1"
2009-10-29  17:27:10:624    1128    a14 Agent     * ServiceID = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}
2009-10-29  17:27:10:624    1128    a14 Misc    Validating signature for C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\SelfUpdate\Default\wuident.cab:
2009-10-29  17:27:10:655    1128    a14 Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2009-10-29  17:27:10:702    1128    a14 Misc    Validating signature for C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\SelfUpdate\Default\wuident.cab:
2009-10-29  17:27:10:702    1128    a14 Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2009-10-29  17:27:10:780    1128    a14 Misc    Validating signature for C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\SelfUpdate\Default\wsus3setup.cab:
2009-10-29  17:27:10:780    1128    a14 Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2009-10-29  17:27:10:796    1128    a14 Setup   ***********  Setup: Checking whether self-update is required  ***********
2009-10-29  17:27:10:796    1128    a14 Setup     * Inf file: C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\SelfUpdate\Default\wsus3setup.inf
2009-10-29  17:27:10:796    1128    a14 Setup   Update NOT required for C:\WINDOWS\system32\cdm.dll: target version = 7.1.6001.65, required version = 7.1.6001.65
2009-10-29  17:27:10:796    1128    a14 Setup   Update NOT required for C:\WINDOWS\system32\wuapi.dll: target version = 7.1.6001.65, required version = 7.1.6001.65
2009-10-29  17:27:10:796    1128    a14 Setup   Update NOT required for C:\WINDOWS\system32\wuapi.dll.mui: target version = 7.1.6001.65, required version = 7.1.6001.65
2009-10-29  17:27:10:796    1128    a14 Setup   Update NOT required for C:\WINDOWS\system32\wuauclt.exe: target version = 7.1.6001.65, required version = 7.1.6001.65
2009-10-29  17:27:10:874    1128    a14 Setup   Update NOT required for C:\WINDOWS\system32\wuaucpl.cpl: target version = 7.1.6001.65, required version = 7.1.6001.65
2009-10-29  17:27:10:874    1128    a14 Setup   Update NOT required for C:\WINDOWS\system32\wuaucpl.cpl.mui: target version = 7.1.6001.65, required version = 7.1.6001.65
2009-10-29  17:27:10:874    1128    a14 Setup   Update NOT required for C:\WINDOWS\system32\wuaueng.dll: target version = 7.1.6001.65, required version = 7.1.6001.65
2009-10-29  17:27:10:874    1128    a14 Setup   Update NOT required for C:\WINDOWS\system32\wuaueng.dll.mui: target version = 7.1.6001.65, required version = 7.1.6001.65
2009-10-29  17:27:10:874    1128    a14 Setup   Update NOT required for C:\WINDOWS\system32\wucltui.dll: target version = 7.1.6001.65, required version = 7.1.6001.65
2009-10-29  17:27:10:874    1128    a14 Setup   Update NOT required for C:\WINDOWS\system32\wucltui.dll.mui: target version = 7.1.6001.65, required version = 7.1.6001.65
2009-10-29  17:27:10:874    1128    a14 Setup   Update NOT required for C:\WINDOWS\system32\wups.dll: target version = 7.1.6001.65, required version = 7.1.6001.65
2009-10-29  17:27:10:874    1128    a14 Setup   Update NOT required for C:\WINDOWS\system32\wups2.dll: target version = 7.1.6001.65, required version = 7.1.6001.65
2009-10-29  17:27:10:874    1128    a14 Setup   Update NOT required for C:\WINDOWS\system32\wuweb.dll: target version = 7.1.6001.65, required version = 7.1.6001.65
2009-10-29  17:27:10:874    1128    a14 Setup     * IsUpdateRequired = No
2009-10-29  17:27:17:468    1128    a14 PT  +++++++++++  PT: Synchronizing server updates  +++++++++++
2009-10-29  17:27:17:468    1128    a14 PT    + ServiceId = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}, Server URL = hxxp://dublindc2/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2009-10-29  17:27:55:157    1128    a14 Agent     * Found 0 updates and 46 categories in search; evaluated appl. rules of 478 out of 678 deployed entities
2009-10-29  17:27:55:173    1128    a14 Agent   *********
2009-10-29  17:27:55:173    1128    a14 Agent   **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
2009-10-29  17:27:55:173    1128    a14 Agent   *************
2009-10-29  17:27:55:189    1128    f1c AU  >>##  RESUMED  ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {59353978-CBA7-4B0B-AFD3-515577D3C16B}]
2009-10-29  17:27:55:189    1128    f1c AU    # 0 updates detected
2009-10-29  17:27:55:189    1128    f1c AU  #########
2009-10-29  17:27:55:189    1128    f1c AU  ##  END  ##  AU: Search for updates [CallId = {59353978-CBA7-4B0B-AFD3-515577D3C16B}]
2009-10-29  17:27:55:189    1128    f1c AU  #############
2009-10-29  17:27:55:189    1128    f1c AU  AU setting next detection timeout to 2009-10-29 21:01:30
2009-10-29  17:27:55:189    1128    f1c AU  Setting AU scheduled install time to 2009-10-30 13:00:00
2009-10-29  17:27:55:251    1128    a14 Report  Uploading 2 events using cached cookie, reporting URL = hxxp://dublindc2/ReportingWebService/ReportingWebService.asmx
2009-10-29  17:27:55:267    1128    a14 Report  Reporter successfully uploaded 2 events.
2009-10-29  17:28:00:173    1128    a14 Report  REPORT EVENT: {BD891590-784B-4001-8116-D83962DAB749}    2009-10-29 17:27:55:173-0000    1   147 101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0   AutomaticUpdates    Success Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client successfully detected 0 updates.
2009-10-29  17:28:00:173    1128    a14 Report  REPORT EVENT: {E578C377-5E09-4F4C-AB28-FE5131E2D6A7}    2009-10-29 17:27:55:173-0000    1
```

I've tried deleting everything in the C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution, stopping the services, rebooting etc. Can anyone decipher the log to see where it's going wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: Your client doesn't see any new updates. Check if they are actually downloaded and active on the server, and apply to the specific clients.

Comment: It's possible they weren't downloaded on the server, which is why there was a delay. Good spot.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a diagnostic with WSUS Client Diagnostic Tool ?
[WSUS Diag Tool](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/7/6/976d1084-d2fd-45a1-8c27-a467c768d8ef/WSUS%20Client%20Diagnostic%20Tool.EXE)

And are you sure that you have approved all the updates in your WSUS server ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and many apologies for not coming back to this until now. It worked eventually, I came back the next day and all the updates were waiting to be installed. Patience is a virtue!

Comment: Good for you, that works it's the most important :)